# Passing ether with call to Solidity function

Tags: transactions, web3js, ether, contract-debugging, contract-invocation

I have deployed a [contract to testnet](http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xf03ce590a9d4d39704343593c86632a107533b58) which appears to function.

I have a function named `contribute` which gets the ether from the **msg.value**.  The function is below and doesn't take any arguments.

I call `contribute` from JavaScript like this:

```
var res = contracts['CrowdFunder'].contract.contribute();
```

How do I specify ether to be sent when calling `contribute`?

Here is `contribute` which expects **msg.value**

```
function contribute() public      
    {
        contributions.push(
            Contribution({
                amount: msg.value,
                contributor: msg.sender
            }) 
        );
        totalRaised += msg.value;             
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pass in an object with a property named `value` and the amount of wei.

Using your example, like:

`contracts['CrowdFunder'].contract.contribute({value: web3.toWei(12, 'ether')});`

Note, in your example `res` will be a transaction hash.