# Unable to send ether to contract

Tags: ether, out-of-gas, fallback-function, wallet-transfer

I am working on private test-net and trying to send ether to contract but ether is not being transferred. I tried using both geth console and Mist.
 
`eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to: "0x2D13f7fbBA77EF39bd21d661bc77cd85ECA0C230", value: web3.toWei(15, "ether"), gas: 1000000})` 
On using `debug.traceTransaction(txHash)` , I am getting 
`invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2 
undefined`
Why can't I send ether to contract?

Comment: What is the fallback function of the contract?

Comment: The fallback function is `function( ) {throw;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract probably has a fallback function that generates an exception or uses more than 1000000 gas (which would itself cause an exception).

Related:

[What does a "bad JUMPDEST" error mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/694/what-does-a-bad-jumpdest-error-mean)

[Why does a Solidity throw consume all gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-does-a-solidity-throw-consume-all-gas)

Comment: So is the fallback function prevents transfer of ether to a contract? If Yes, How? I mean how does it know whether the address of `to: `is of an account or of a contract?

Comment: Yes, your fallback function is what is rejecting the Ether: I also asked that question http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/how-does-a-fallback-function-rejecting-ether-work and see the comments to the answer too.  Basically, the only difference a contract has is non-empty code http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/769/42, and code always executes when it receives a transaction/message.

Comment: So if I am implementing [buy and sell functions](https://www.ethereum.org/token#automatic-selling-and-buying), there exchange of coins and ether occurs between account and contract. So how are these functions able to transfer ether to and from contract? also if I can not send ether to contract, How I am supposed to use  [Autorefill](https://www.ethereum.org/token#autorefill) functionality.  I asked about working of buy and sell in [this question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7616/unable-to-understand-buy-and-sell-functions) (view comments).

Comment: You can send ether to the contract by using the `buy` function (instead of the fallback function).  Example: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/passing-ether-with-call-to-solidity-function  I also commented on your other question.