# How to retrieve the Contract account balance in web3 or in geth command line?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, balances

I have created a private network with miner node using Ethereum. Then I deployed an Ethereum smart contract in the network. I have got the contract address as **"0x045bfe22453a9ca06aff4bdc5d7f5870eba121bd"**

Now from my eth.coinbase I would like to transfer some ethers to the contract account.

After unlocking the account, I used the code

```
  eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase,to:"0x045bfe22453a9ca06aff4bdc5d7f5870eba121bd",value:web3.toWei(3,"ether"),gas:'1000000'});
```

After doing this, I have checked for **eth.pendingtransactions**, those got mined and added to blocks.

I debugged the transactionReceipt, could not able to get the data anything.

How to get the balance in contract account?

Answer (score 19):

To check the balance you can do:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(contract.options.address)
```

Or:

```
web3.eth.getBalance("0x045bfe22453a9ca06aff4bdc5d7f5870eba121bd")
```

To transfer balance on a contract without calling a function the contract must have a payable fallback function.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function

Answer (score 1):

The contract probably has a fallback function that generates an exception or uses more than `1000000` gas (which would itself cause an exception).The fallback function goes by:

```
function( ) {throw;}
```

You can check this by using following code snippet:

```
var status= debug.traceTransaction("your_transaction_hash);
if (status.structLogs.length > 0) {
  console.log(status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error)
}
```

And if you output as:

```
"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"
```

Then your code `throws`.

> What could be the way to get the balance in contract account.
>   If you are comfortable using `geth` use :

```
eth.getBalance("0x045bfe22453a9ca06aff4bdc5d7f5870eba121bd")
```

Or you can also see your contract balance in Mist for that you have to watch the contract. 
**Solution:** 
From comments section :
**Add `payable` modifier to the fallback function** to allow contract to recieve ethers. You need to add payable modifier to any function that seeks to recieve ethers.

Comment: Simple calling 

eth.getBalance("0x045bfe22453a9ca06aff4bdc5d7f5870eba121bd")

Return Zero.

How can I restrict the "invalid jump destination error".

Thanks.

Comment: For that, you have to remove the fallback function from your contract that prevents contract from accidently accepting ethers.

Comment: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function

As per this, we couldn't remove the callback function. How can I test the callback function execution costly less than 2300 gas.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for pointing out. I was not updated with changes in new version of solidity. As the doc says: "this function is executed whenever the contract receives plain Ether (without data)", so you can send some data along with `sendTransaction`. Also you can use buy function of token to send ethers to contract [see here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/passing-ether-with-call-to-solidity-function)

Comment: Thanks. I have resolved it. Able to retrieve the contract balances by adding the payable modifier to the fallback function.

Comment: Great. You can update the answer for others.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using newer versions of solidity to compile your contract, you need to ensure your fallback function is defined, and has the `payable` modifier:

```
contract IsPayable {
  function () payable {}
}
```